# JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE not working after changing to PHP7

Tags: php, json, php-7

I have a script that gets data from a database and encodes it as json.
It was working properly in PHP 5.6

```
$datos_nbr=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      echo json_encode($datos_nbr, JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );
```

After switching to PHP 7, if the string contains special characters ( as á,é,ñ ) it shows "null" in the field. It works well with the other strings.

no special characters -> [{"idpersona":1372,"nombre":"LANCIO JORGE"}]

with special characters -> [{"idpersona":101860,"nombre":null}]

Putting print_r before the json_encode shows the data is there
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idpersona] => 101860
            [nombre] => CABA�A AGUADA
        )

)

I tried

```
      echo json_encode(array_map('utf8_encode',$datos_nbr));
```

and

```
$datos_nbr= array_map('htmlentities', $datos_nbr);
echo (html_entity_decode(json_encode($datos_nbr)));
```

adding or not JSON_PARTIAL_OUTPUT_ON_ERROR and JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE

Using array_map I only get [null] as answer.